# Is it possible to sort an array prop using a method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting

I currently have an array prop that populates a table with dummy data:
`paymentHistoryList: Array`

There are four columns, but I'm just focusing on Date for now. What I'm trying to do is to be able to sort this table by selecting the table header Date, triggering an ascending/descending sort. By default, it's sorted in Descending order and `this.sortByPostedDate` is already set to `true`. Currently, I have my table header set up like this:

```
<th v-on:click="sortBy('postedDate')">DATE</th>
```

And my method like so. Again, there will be a few more cases built into this:

```
sortBy(column) {
  switch (column) {
    case 'postedDate':
      if (this.sortByPostedDate) {
        this.paymentHistoryList.sort((a, b) => a.paymentScheduledDate - b.paymentScheduledDate);
      } else {
        this.paymentHistoryList.sort((a, b) => b.paymentScheduledDate - a.paymentScheduledDate);
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Here's a snippet of how the table is made:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-on:click="sortBy('postedDate')">DATE</th>
      <th class="table-cell">AMOUNT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <radio-group>
    <template v-for="(payment) in paymentHistoryList">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ payment.paymentScheduledDate }}</td>
        <td>{{ payment.paymentAmount }}</td>
      </tr>
    </template>
    </radio-group>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, the paymentHistoryList won't sort when clicking on the Date table header. I've confirmed that the header recognizes when it's being clicked, but there seems to be a disconnect when trying to run the sortBy function.

I've seen this implemented where the table information was brought in via computed mapState, rather than a prop. Is the prop the issue? If so, is there a way to implement this while maintaining the prop?

Comment: The question is unclear. What is the problem? Do you get an error? Does `paymentHistoryList` not sort?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Whoops, sorry! The paymentHistoryList doesn't sort.

Comment: What is the content of `paymentScheduledDate`? Is it a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) a library object like [`Moment`](https://momentjs.com/) something else?

Comment: My guess is that `paymentScheduledDate` is a string and when you do `"2020-10-16" - "2020-10-13"` you'll end up with `NaN`. `sort` expects a positive, negative or zero return value. If everything ends up being `NaN` nothing is sorted.

Comment: @3limin4t0r ```paymentScheduledDate``` is a string. Pretty sure this is the root issue here, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

[As you specified in the comments](/questions/64392650/is-it-possible-to-sort-an-array-prop-using-a-method?noredirect=1#comment113928755_64392650), `paymentScheduledDate` is a string. Which means that that `a.paymentScheduledDate - b.paymentScheduledDate` is not going to work when using the sort method.

`sort` is executed and the provided array is sorted. However when subtracting to date strings you will end up with `NaN`. Due to all comparisons returning `NaN` every element stay on the exact same index.

```
"2020-10-15" - "2020-10-20" //=> NaN
```

So how do you sort dates? If they are in standard ISO 8601 formatting `YYYY-MM-DD` you could simply sort in alphabetical order. This is achieved by comparing the two strings using the `<` (less than) and `>` (greater than) operators.

```
"2020-10-15" < "2020-10-20" //=> true
"2020-10-15" > "2020-10-20" //=> false
```

Since [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expects an negative, positive or zero result from the callback function you could write something like this:

```
const asc  = (fn) => (a, b) => (a = fn(a), b = fn(b), -(a < b) || +(a > b));
const desc = (fn) => (a, b) => asc(fn)(b, a);
```

`asc` runs the provided function `fn` for both argument `a` and `b`. Then compares the results using `a < b`, if the result is `true` return `-1` (`-true //=> -1`). If `false` test `a > b`, if the result is `true` return `1` (`+true //=> 1`). If `false` return `0` (`+false //=> 0`). `desc` reverses the argument, which in turn reverses the result.

If the the string are not in standard ISO 8601 formatting you will have to parse the string first first. Which can be done with for example [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). This will return a timestamp which can be subtracted from each other: `timestampA - timestampB`.

Here is an example sorting the date strings alphabetically:

```js
const asc  = (fn) => (a, b) => (a = fn(a), b = fn(b), -(a < b) || a > b);
const desc = (fn) => (a, b) => asc(fn)(b, a);

Vue.component("payment-history", {
  props: ["paymentHistoryList"],
  methods: {
    sortBy(column) {
      switch (column) {
        case 'postedDate':
          this.sortByPostedDate = !this.sortByPostedDate;
          const order = this.sortByPostedDate ? asc : desc;
          this.paymentHistoryList.sort(order(payment => payment.paymentScheduledDate));
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  },
  template: `
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th v-on:click="sortBy('postedDate')">DATE</th>
          <th class="table-cell">AMOUNT</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <template v-for="(payment) in paymentHistoryList">
          <tr>
            <td>{{ payment.paymentScheduledDate }}</td>
            <td>{{ payment.paymentAmount }}</td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `
});

new Vue({
  el: '#payment-history-container',
  data: {
    paymentHistory: [
      {paymentScheduledDate: "2020-01-15", paymentAmount: 1},
      {paymentScheduledDate: "2020-10-10", paymentAmount: 2},
      {paymentScheduledDate: "2002-10-20", paymentAmount: 3},
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="payment-history-container">
  <payment-history :payment-history-list="paymentHistory"></payment-history>
</div>
```